# Match public IP addresses with user-supplied netmasks

Tags: java, networking, ip, subnet

Recently I was given a task at my company where I have to create a function like this:

```
boolean addrMatch(String IP, String netMask);
```

**This has nothing to do with routing.** We have a network service that will use this function. The IP parameter varies upon all requests, the netMask parameter is user-supplied. The function must tell that an actual IP address matches with the supplied netmask or not. This is something like the user tells our system to only serve requests on the public internet to a specific subset of IP addresses, not all of them.
My networking related knowledge is far from complete, so I did a deep search on the topic, but I didn't get very far.
What I know (or been told): all the two parameteres are valid IP addresses or netmasks in xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx notation. I have to do a bitwise AND on them (obviously after converting them into BitSet or at least byte[] array). But I guess this is not the complete algorithm.
So my question: what is the correct algorithm for matching an IP address with a netmask?

ps.: I'm working in Java, but I need the generic method.

Answer (score 0):

A netmask is just a bitmask. Basically if `address & netmask != 0` the address is in the subnet represented by the netmask. The implementation details you have to cope with are bytes instead of bits, and varying numbers of bytes depending on whether you have IPv4 or IPv6. But it's basically trivial.

Comment: I converted IP and mask into byte[] arrays and did res[i] = ip[i] & mask[i]. The result contains 4 int numbers. If the result doesn't contain any zeros, the IP matches with the mask, but if contains at least one zero, the IP cannot be in the subnet represented by the mask? Sorry for the basic questions :)

Comment: @gyabraham If any bit is non zero, it matches.